# Im getting error while tring to read .fasta file in python

Tags: python, fasta

im trying to read a .fasta file as a dictionary and extract the header and sequence separately.there are several headers and sequences in the file.
an example below.

```
header= CMP12
sequence=agcgtmmnngucnncttsckkld
```

but when i try to read a fasta file using the function read_f and test it using print(dict.keys()) i get an empty list.

```
def read_f(fasta):
    '''Read a file from a FASTA format'''

    dictionary = {}
    with open(fasta) as file:
        text = file.readlines()
        print(text)

    name=''
    seq= ''
    #Create blocks of fasta text for each sequence, EXCEPT the last one
    for line in text:
        if line[0]=='>':
            dictionary[name] = seq
            name=line[1:].strip()
            seq=''

        else: seq = seq + line.strip()
    yield name,seq


fasta= ("sample.prot.fasta")
dict = read_f(fasta)

print(dict.keys())
```

this is the error i get:

```
'generator' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: Your function name is either wrong or used wrong. Please fix

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code: typo, indentation, shadowing builtins

Comment: Unrelated to your exact question, but it would be best if instead of trying to write your own FASTA reader, you can use an existing well-tested one, e.g. from [BioPython](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).  It's already a well-solved problem so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `yield` keyword implies that when you call the function `read_fasta`, the function is not executed. Instead, a generator is returned and you have to iterate this generator to get the elements the function yields.
In concrete terms, replacing `dict = read_fasta(fasta)` by `dict = read_fasta(*fasta)` should do the job (* is the operator for unpacking).

Answer (score 0):

As Iguananaut already mentioned, Bipython helps you out. (requires biopython package installed)
See [Biopython "sequence file to dictionary"](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec63)

```
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta= "sample.prot.fasta"

seq_record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(fasta, "fasta"))
```